# why python decorator result like this..?

Tags: python, python-decorators

these days, i study python decorator,, and my question code is this.

```
import functools
def my_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def say_hello():
    print("hello!")

ret = my_decorator(say_hello)
ret()
```

actually, i expect this result

```
Something is happening before the function is called.
hello!
Something is happening after the function is called.
```

but real output is like this.

```
Something is happening before the function is called.
Something is happening before the function is called.
hello!
Something is happening after the function is called.
Something is happening after the function is called.
```

can someone tell me why result like this?

Comment: because you are using the decorator 2 times, the first with `@my_decorator` and the second invoking it with: `my_decorator(say_hello)`

Comment: this question should be closed as a typo, it won't be helpful for anybody else from OP especially with this kind of clickbait title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have decorated your function `say_hello` twice.

Generally, in examples of decorators, the function wrapper is explicitly called i.e:

```
def outer(f):
  def wrapper():
     f()
  return wrapper

def stuff():
  print('hello from stuff')

new_stuff = outer(stuff)
new_stuff()
```

Which will give `'hello from stuff'` outputted to the console, as `new_stuff` is storing the function object `wrapper`, returned from `outer`. However, using the `@decorator` syntactic sugar automatically performs the first call i.e `outer(stuff)`. Thus, the example above is comparable to:

```
def outer(f):
  def wrapper():
    f()
  return wrapper

@outer
def stuff():
  print('hello from stuff')
```

Thus, in your example, simply calling `say_hello`  (`say_hello()`) will correctly output

```
Something is happening before the function is called.
hello!
Something is happening after the function is called.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a decorator like this:

```
@my_decorator
def say_hello():
```

what it actually does behind the scene is to do:

```
say_hello = my_decorator(say_hello)
```

so if you do:

```
ret = my_decorator(say_hello)
```

you're actually calling the decorator twice, and hence the double messages you see as a result.